# How {async:false} works in jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization

I know why and how to use `{async:false}` in jQuery AJAX request.

But what I need is how this works synchronously? What is the magic behind this?

Comment: Because the native XMLHTTPRequest object provides the possibility to make synchronous requests. You can assume that it does that by pausing the thread in which JS runs.

Comment: @FelixKling +1 for your commennt . Let me ask you this ,How will you design javascript function that runs synchronously with other function   ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Functions are synchronous by default. If you are working with an async function, you cannot make it synchronous. The browser doesn't expose such a level of control to content scripts.

Comment: @FelixKling 
**Scenario :**

`<body onload="myOnloadFuncA();myOnloadFuncB();">`

myOnloadFuncA() -Performing some animation and XHR request so on..(Runs appprox : 10 sec – MAX time)

Now function “myOnloadFuncB()” have to start process after “myOnloadFuncA()” completes, Untill it have to Wait .How will you do this ?

Comment: By making `myOnloadFuncA` accepts a callback that is executed once all its async operations have been completed. `myOnloadFuncB` will then be that callback. You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [the native `XMLHTTPRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) provides the possibility to [make synchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29):

> **async**
>   An optional boolean parameter, defaulting to true, indicating whether or not to perform the operation asynchronously.

You can assume that it does that by pausing the thread in which JS runs.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, is that when async is false, then it will wait until the [`readyState`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate) is set to `DONE`, which as defined by the W3, is:

> The data transfer has been completed or something went wrong during the transfer (e.g. infinite redirects).

So basically when the request is completed, it will continue on.

Comment: Why would you think jQuery uses this library and not the browser's native XMLHTTPRequest object?

Comment: @sircapsalot What does `fSynchronizeValues` do in your snippet ?

Comment: https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest/blob/master/XMLHttpRequest.js#L509  Look through the source yourself, it'll make sense :)

Comment: @FelixKling all my searching led me to this library being the actual source for the XMLHttpRequest.  Either way, the logic is the same.  with or without the source, it still shows the concept of monitoring the request state, and proceeding to execute actions AFTER, if async is set to true.

Comment: @sircapsalot: *"all my searching led me to this library being the actual source for the XMLHttpRequest"* What exactly did you search for? Does jQuery refer to this library anywhere?  You can't make make an asynchronous call synchronous without access to browser internal APIs. The library still relies on the native `XMLHTTPRequest` object: https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest/blob/master/XMLHttpRequest.js#L134.

Comment: I know that.  It's a moot point, i don't know why you are trying to disprove anything when there isn't anything to prove. i'm not trying to say that this *is* the actual source, nor does it even matter.  I'm not being pedantic about these things, this answer is just to show the proof of concept `:)`

Comment: just trying to help out

Comment: But what exactly does it show? It doesn't explain how jQuery makes the call synchronous. The code you posted is irrelevant to the question. In the worst case it gives readers the false impression that it's possible to make asynchronous functions synchronous. I understand that you are trying to help, but answers should still be *correct* and actually target the question.

Comment: you're right about the code, it is irrelevant. Edited.

Comment: thanks for the help @FelixKling, it's always nice to find out ways to improve my answers.